# Add dateCreated field to join table in Grails

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy

I have a M:M relationship between User and Badge which creates a join table called "user_badges". This table has the fields: user_id and badge_id. Is there a way to get the standard date_created fields on this table?

```
class Badge {

static belongsTo = User
static hasMany = [users: User]
}

class User {
 static hasMany = [badges: Badge]
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically, you need to change the mapping so that the M:M relationship is expressed as two 1:M relationships. Here's an example where the joining class is `BadgeOwner` (so by default the generated join table will be named `badge_owner`)

```
class Badge {    
  static hasMany = [owners: BadgeOwner]
}

class User {
  static hasMany = [owners: BadgeOwner]
}

class BadgeOwner {
  static belongsTo = [user: User, badge: Badge]
  Date dateCreated 
  Date lastUpdated
}
```

Comment: For a complete discussion on this idea see: http://www.grails.org/Many-to-Many+Mapping+without+Hibernate+XML

Answer (score 4):

If it has additional properties, it's not a join table. It's a separate entity. So, map it accordingly :-)

Answer (score 0):

I am doing same kind of research. May be this is a better way.Please comment below if I am wrong.

```
class Badge {    
  /* Declare Variables */
  static belongsTo = [BadgeOwner]
}

class User {
  /* Declare Variables */
  static belongsTo = [BadgeOwner]
}

class BadgeOwner {
  User user
  Badge badge
  Date dateCreated 
  Date lastUpdated
}
```